# images cannot be an array or an object - sequelize, postgres, nodejs, multer

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, multer

I am trying to make a post request to the database, the datatypes of images is a string and i can upload one, two or multiple images.

How should i store the images?

Here is my Posts model

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../config/database");

const Posts = db.define(
 "post",
{
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true,
},
title: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
images: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
    }})
```

Here is my post method:

```
 router.post(
"/",
[
upload.array("images", config.get("maxImageCount")),
imageResize,
 ],
 async (req, res) => {
const paths = await req.files.map((file) => ({ fileName: file.filename }));
Posts.create({
  title: req.body.title,
  images: paths,     
  }).then(
  () => {
    res.status(201).send({
      msg: "upload successful",
    });
  },
  (validation) => {
    res.status(422).json({
      errors: validation.errors.map((error) => {
        return {
          fieldName: error.path,
          message: error.message,
        };
      }),
    });
    }
  );
 }
);
```

Why do i keep getting an error???

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "fieldName": "images",
        "message": "images cannot be an array or an object"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code defines `const paths = ...` but then your `Posts.create()` uses `path` with no "S". I think this is a typo in your question though because `req.files.map()` will generate an array. You can't insert an array into a column value which is what the error is telling you.

Comment: just updated the question path was a typo in my question, how should i approach this then? i tried using images: JSON.stringify(paths) and it works, i dont get an error but my response looks like this: "images":"[{\"fileName\":\"image0\"}]" . i did so research and found out the JSON.stringify an array is a wrong approach.